# What are the practical impacts of Wassenaar Arrangement to crypto development?

Tags: encryption

Wassenaar Arrangement limits transport of high-grade crypto hardware/software since decades, if I don't err. What are its practical impacts in that direction?

In particular, does it hinder in any sense publication of highly secure codes in proceedings of scientific conferences, on the Internet, or sending of the corresponding implementations as attachments via emails anywhere in the world?